# Creating a specified number of strings

Tags: string, vb.net, random

I want to create a specified number of strings in a VB.NET Console Application. I've tried this code but it throws an exception:

> NullReferenceException: Object Reference not set into an instance of an Object.

This is the code:

```
Module RandStrConsole

Dim r As New Random
Dim s As String
Dim result As System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim MaxChar As Integer


Sub Main()

    Console.Write("Enter String: ") : s = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Maxchar: ") : MaxChar = Console.ReadLine

    For i As Integer = 1 To MaxChar

        Dim idx As Integer = r.Next(0, s.Count - 1)
        result = sb.Append(s.Substring(idx, 1)) 'NullReferenceException: Object Reference not set into an instance of an Object.
        result.ToString()

    Next

    Console.WriteLine(result)
    Console.ReadKey()


End Sub

End Module
```

The commented section indicates where the exception happened.

Comment: Glad I could be of help! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent, I hope you can reach more people to help!

Comment: Your issue explained in detail [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the `StringBuilders`. You must use the [**`New` keyword**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx).

```
Dim result As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
```